# will loop decrease the utilization of the GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, gpu

In PyTorch, I have a loop in my DeepLearning Pipeline's forward part to normalize the intermediate result.

Will it run on CPU and decrease the utilization of the GPU?

some snippet as follow:

```
def forward(self):
    ...
    for b in range(batch_size):
        self.points[b] = self.unit_cube(self.points[b])
    ....
```

Comment: Python doesn’t run on the gpu unless you use a library to compile something like glsl to a compute shader and bind it to python. Otherwise, everything you do with python is done through the python interpreter, which runs on the cpu.

Comment: @AwesomeCronk It's tagged with PyTorch which is a library which gives easy GPU access for Deep Learning projects.

Comment: @Multihunter Ahhh... I completely missed that. Thank you for correcting that!

Answer (score 2):

In Pytorch, whether an operation is done on the GPU or CPU is decided by where the data is. One of the main selling points of Pytorch is that you don't (usually) have to care where the data is; the interface is the same.

If the tensor data is on the GPU, then the operation is done on the GPU. If it's on the CPU, then the operation is done on the CPU. How you choose to organise those operations (`if`s, `for loop`s, etc) have no impact on it.

```py
>>> import torch
>>> a = torch.randn(3,4,5)
>>> b = a.cuda()
>>> a.device
device(type='cpu')
>>> b.device
device(type='cuda', index=0)
>>> c = b
>>> for x in range(10):
...   c = c * 2
... 
>>> c.device
device(type='cuda', index=0)
```

In the above example, I used a for loop to double `b` 10 times, storing the result in c. This was all done on the GPU, and I equally could have done this on `a`, making it happen on the CPU.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also wonder to know whether the 'print' function will break the GPU process? For example, I print the output to the shell or a file.

Comment: Few operations will modify tensors in-place and when they do, they are explicitly denoted as such. Printing a GPU tensor doesn't make the tensor not on the GPU for the same reason that `print(a*2)` doesn't make `a` equal to the value printed. And for the same reason that `b = a.cuda()` results in two separate tensors, one on the GPU and the other on the CPU. But, generally, you should try it and see. If you have a tensor, and `b.device` says `cuda`, then it is *always* a GPU tensor.

Comment: Actually, I'm training an image segmentation project, the utilization of the GPU change from 0 to 55% all the time. I wonder to know if it's because of the `print` function.

Comment: Ah, debugging GPU utilisation is tricky because it's all asynchronous and inscrutable.  The method I've had the most success with is to write a separate script that repeatedly runs some operation and estimate how long each one takes. e.g. make some fake data, then do a loop of doing `model.forward` 10000 times and see how long it takes with/without the operation in question. Generally, though, `print` is very unlikely to be causing that. Less-than-maximum GPU utilisation is usually because of the data loading pipeline. Make sure you have that running in a few threads.